# Number of permutation with exact k inversions

Tags: permutation

Let `A = [a1,a2,...,an]` be a permutation of integers `1`,`2`,...,`n`.

A pair of indices `(i,j)`, where `1<=i<=j<=n`, is an inversion of the permutation `A` if `ai>aj`. We are given integers `n>0` and `k>=0`. What number of n-element permutations contain exactly `k` inversions?

This is a programming problem and I am looking for a DP solution. Did anyone try this?