# Count Number of Sequences

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, permutation, discrete-mathematics

The question is:
Given a sequence of positive integers ***A={1,2,3,...,N}***.
 Count the number of sequences you can get after making  ***K***  adjacent swaps on it for a given  ***N*** ?
My approach:
My algorithm to solve such a programming question is very naive. I could only think of making all the possible k swaps and then count the sequences. 
Can anyone help me out with a better algorithm?

Comment: Perhaps move this question to: http://math.stackexchange.com/  Seems like pretty basic prob & stats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Inversions

The key to this type of problem (of swapping adjacent elements) is to consider the number of inversions in the permutation after each swap.

Two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j.

The number of inversions in a permutation is the number of pairs of elements which form an inversion.

The reason this is useful is because whenever you perform a swap of adjacent elements, the inversion count either goes up by 1 or goes down by 1.

### Hint to solve problem

Therefore, after K swaps the total number of inversions must be one of the following values: K,K-2,K-4, etc.

So we have reduced the problem to one of counting the number of permutations with K or K-2 or K-4, etc. inversions.  The number of permutations with a given number of inversions is given by the [triangle of Mahonian numbers](http://oeis.org/A008302).

### Code to solve problem

All you need to do is to compute row N of the triangle (code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372991/number-of-n-element-permutations-with-exactly-k-inversions)) and then sum the appropriate entries:

```
row = mahonian_row(N)
print sum(row[n] for n in range(K+1) if n%2==K%2 and n<len(row))
```

Comment: What if it is a swap of any two elements rather than adjacent?

Comment: In that case you should start thinking about the permutation in terms of its cycle decomposition.  The cycle decomposition of a permutation would tell you how many non-adjacent swaps are needed (by simply subtracting 1 from the lengths of the cycles), so you will end up counting the number of possible decompositions into cycles with a length constraint.  This is likely to involve a sum of entries in Pascal's triangle instead of the Mahonian triangle.