# Find the total number of permutation with K inversions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have been given the number `N`. I have to find all the permutations of numbers `1..N` such that the total number of inversions in the array is `K`.

```
For example: (all the following permutations have exactly 2 inversions) 
N=4 , K=2
(1,4,2,3) , (1,3,4,2) , (2,1,4,3) , (3,1,2,4) and (2,3,1,4).
```

**My Approach:**
Dynamic Programming: let `dp[i][j]` hold number of ways such that position `i` is responsible for `j` number of inversion.

```
dp[n][0]=1
 for(int i=n-1;i>=1;i--){

      int x = Math.min(k,n-i); // Maximum Number of inversion i position can do

      for(int j=0;j<=x;j++){

          for(int v=0;v<=j;v++){
                dp[i][j]+=dp[i+1][v];
            }

      }
```

But my approach give me individual position inversions, how can I get the total ways?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of n-element permutations with exactly k inversions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372991/number-of-n-element-permutations-with-exactly-k-inversions)

Comment: @A.Sarid still can you improve my current implementation what i am missing

Answer (score 0):

Since for any permutation of `1,2...N-1`, we can insert `N`, at position `j`, adding a total of `N-j` inversions, the total number of permutations of `1,2...N` with `k` inversions may be calculated by

```
T(N,k) = T(N-1,k) + T(N-1,k-1) + T(N-1,k-2) ... + T(N-1,0)
```

JavaScript example:

```js
function f(N,K){
  var M = [[1]];

  for (var n=1; n<=N; n++){
    M[n] = new Array((n-1)*n/2 + 1).fill(0);
    
    for (var k=0; k<=(n-1)*n/2; k++){
      for (var j=Math.min(k,(n-2)*(n-1)/2); j>= Math.max(0,k-n+1); j--){
        M[n][k] += M[n-1][j];
      }
    }
  }
  
  return M;
}

var res = f(5,10);

for (var i=0; i< res.length; i++){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res[i]));
}
```

Comment: i have also done the same things `dp[i][j]+=dp[i+1][v]`; but when N=3,K=3 it gives me 0

Comment: Maximum # of inversions for N = 2 is 1, no? So for T=3, the only place we can add it to T(2,1) to get 3 inversions would be in position 0, I think. Something like: `T(2,0) = {(1,2)}; T(2,1) = {(2,1)}; T(3,3) = {(3,2,1)}`